# Using google spreadsheet offset

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to copy data from one sheet to another in Google spreadsheets by having the user click a submit button for their timesheet. I got the button working for the most part using a google apps script, however I do not want the data getting the copied over from the previous time the selected the submit button. Here is my code:

```
var row = "A1:J20";
var current = row;

function submitButton(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("{id}");

  var source_sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("CumulativeHours");

  var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("B8:K28");
  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange(current);

  source_range.copyTo(target_range, {contentsOnly:true});

  target_range.offset(20,0,20);
  current = target_range;
  source_range.clearContent();
}
```

Am I going about this correctly (I'm basically using a hidden sheet as a sort of table where everybody's hours gets written to/read from within a given week ending)? Is there a way to offset the cells every time the user selects submit and have Google spreadsheets remember this offset so that it may offset it to a different point each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var lastRow = target_sheet..getLastRow();

Docs: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow()